# Trying to get rid of SQL injection Vulnerablity

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

The vulnerability program I have tells me that I have SQL injection vulnerability in two of my web pages and I cannot seem to understand what is causing it. My code is as follows:

authcheck.php

```
<html>
<?php 
header ("X-Frame-Options: DENY"); 
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
?>
    <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tutors.css">   
   <title>CSTutot Authenticate</title>
</head>

<body> 

<?php

    // Needed For SQLFunctions getFaculty call
    require_once('Includes/SQLFunctions.php');

    // Needed For Utils check_input call
    require_once('Includes/Utils.php');



    // Retrieve Post Data
    $wsuser = check_input($_POST["wsuser"]);    
    $wsemail = check_input($_POST["wsemail"]);  

    // Authenticate User
    $student = getStudent($wsuser,$wsemail);        

        if (strlen($student->getTychoname())==0)
        {
         // Show the login form again.
         include('index.html');  
    ?>
         <p></p>
     <p></p>
     <div><table id="myerror">
     <tr><td>               
     <h4>Login Error</h4>
     </td></tr>
     <tr><td>
     Sorry, the username and email do not match any current account.
     </td></tr>
     <tr><td>   
     Try again, or create an account using the link above.
     </td></tr>
     </table>
     </div>

  <?php  
    }           
        else 
        {
            // Set the session information
                    session_start();  
                    $_SESSION['wsuser'] = $wsuser;                  
                    include('SearchSessions.php');  
        }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

My second page that is giving me the same vulnerability is as follows:

```
<html>
<?php 
header ("X-Frame-Options: DENY"); 
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
?>
    <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tutors.css">   
   <title>Create Student </title>
</head>
<body OnLoad="document.createstudent.firstname.focus();"> 

<?php   

        if(isset($_POST["CreateSubmit"])) 
        {        

        validate_form();             
        } 
        else 
        {               
            $messages = array();
        show_form($messages);  
    } 


function show_form($messages) {         
        // Show the page header
        include('Includes/Header.php'); 
        require_once('Includes/Utils.php');     

        if (count($messages) > 0 ) 
      {     
        echo "<p></p>";
        echo "<div><table id='myresults'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<h2>Warning! Form Entry Errors Exist.</h2>";
        echo "<h4>Please revise based on the following issues and submit again.</h4>";      
        echo "<ol>";  


          foreach ($messages as $m) 
          {   
            echo "<li> $m </li>";     
          }
          echo "</ol>";
          echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
          echo "</table></div>";      
          echo "<p></p>";
        }  

        // Assign post values if exist
        $firstname="";
        $lastname="";
        $wsname="";
        $email="";
        if (isset($_POST["firstname"]))
          $firstname=check_input($_POST["firstname"]);
      if (isset($_POST["lastname"]))
          $lastname=check_input($_POST["lastname"]);      
        if (isset($_POST["wsname"]))
          $wsname=check_input($_POST["wsname"]);  
        if (isset($_POST["email"]))
          $email=check_input($_POST["email"]);

    echo "<p></p>";
    echo "<h2> Request Student Tutor Account</h2>";
    echo "<p></p>";     
    ?>
<h5>Complete the information in the form below and click Submit to create your account. All fields are required.</h5>
    <form name="createstudent" method="POST" action="createStudent.php">    
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" id="mylogin">            
            <tr>
                <td width="157">Firstname:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value='<?php echo $firstname ?>' size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="157">Lastname:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value='<?php echo $lastname ?>' size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="157">WebTycho username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="wsname" value='<?php echo $wsname ?>' size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="157">Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" value='<?php echo $email ?>' size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="157"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="CreateSubmit"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
    </table>            
    </form>

    <?php
} // End Show form

function validate_form()
{
    require_once('Includes/Utils.php'); 
    require_once('Includes/FormObjects.php');       
    require_once('Includes/SQLFunctions.php');      

    $messages = array();
  $redisplay = false;
  // Assign values
  $firstname = check_input($_POST["firstname"]);
  $lastname = check_input($_POST["lastname"]);
  $wsname = check_input($_POST["wsname"]);
  $email = check_input($_POST["email"]);

  // Just check for null values and email format
  if (strlen($firstname)==0)
  {
      $redisplay = true;
      $messages[]="Please enter your Firstname.";
  }         
  if (strlen($lastname)==0)
  {
      $redisplay = true;
      $messages[]="Please enter your lastname.";
  }         
  if (strlen($wsname)==0)
  {
      $redisplay = true;
      $messages[]="Please enter your WebTycho username.";
  }         
  if (strlen($email)==0)
  {
      $redisplay = true;
      $messages[]="Please enter your Email address.";
  }         
  if ($redisplay) 
  {
        show_form($messages);                   
  }
  else 
  {

    // Show the page header
        include('Includes/Header.php'); 
    $student = new StudentClass($firstname,$lastname,$email,$wsname);
    $count = countStudent($student);          
    // Check for accounts that already exist and Do insert
    if ($count==0) 
    {       
        $res = insertStudent($student);
        echo "<h3>Welcome to the CS Tutor program!</h3> ";
                echo "<h3>click here to <a href='index.html' >login</a></h3> ";

    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<h3>A student account with that WenTycho username already exists.</h3> ";
        echo "<h3>Please <a href='index.html'> login</a> using $wsname </h3>";
    }

  }

}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not included the whole code. I think I localized it to the code that I have shown here. If you need the whole code let me know and I will display it for you. Thanks.

Comment: Use stored procedure to get things from your database or use parameterized query

Comment: You code doesn't show where the SQL being executed. Can you provide more detail on that code? And please check if you did:
- Filter bad characters from $_POST (with filter_input: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).
- Escape variables before giving them to SQL (mysqli_escape_string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)

Comment: This is the answer page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php